# Linq split list into sublists then iterate

Tags: linq

I've got a `list: User{name, groupname}` and I've got a function `AddGroupMemberstip` that takes a list of users and a groupname. I need to split up the users based on their groupname, then feed this into this function.

e.g. I ideally would like to do

```
var groups = users.<SOME LINQ FUNCTION>(u => u.groupname);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
   AddGroupMembership(users.value, users.key);
}
```

where `users.value` would be a `IEnumerable<User>` and `users.key` would be the groupname which they all share (for that subgroup).

Please can someone suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
foreach (var g in users.GroupBy(u => u.groupname))
{
    AddGroupMembership(g, g.Key);
}
```

Each group `g` is itself an `IEnumerable<User>`, so there is no `.value` property access when passing the first parameter to `AddGroupMembership`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this:

```
var grouped = from user in users
              group user by user.groupname into groupedUsers
              select new {
                  users = groupedUsers,
                  groupName = groupedUsers.FirstOrDefault().groupName
              };
```

This will give you a list of groups of users, which you could then iterate:

```
foreach (var group in grouped) {
    AddGroupMembership(group.users, group.groupName);
}
```

It's a bit more verbose than Jons answer, and I'm not 100% sure I have the syntax correct, but it's the same basic idea.